# databricks 500k rows x 4000 col table - sql to unpivot ~3800 of the cols into rows & retain column names

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I have a matrix with approx 4000 columns and 500k rows
I'm trying to end up with a dataset where nearly all of the 4000 cols are unpivoted against the remaining ID columns. The name of the unpivoted columns is important and has to be retained

```
before
| ID | A | B | C |...4000 columns | ZZZ999 |
|101 | 1 | 1 | 1 |            ... |      1 |
|201 | 0 | 0 | 1 |            ... |      0 |

after

| ID | col_name | col_val |
|101 |        A |       1 |
|101 |        B |       1 |
|101 |        C |       1 |
|... |       ...|      ...|
|101 |   ZZZ999 |       1 |
|201 |        A |       0 |
|201 |        B |       0 |
|201 |        C |       1 |
|... |       ...|      ...|
|201 |   ZZZ999 |       0 |
```

I can unpivot and just get the values by going to an array and exploding it but i cant figure out how to get the column names too or which intermediate datatype (struct? json?) I should go to before smearing it against the remaing columns

I have the list of the names of the ~4k 'to unpivot' columns listed in another table so i can dynamically generate a list there

there are 94 columns i need to retain as columns. Would be good if i didn't have to hardcode them but it's manageable

needs to be sql only too. Any links or suggestions?